# How do you sql query all in stock products by category ID in M2?

Tags: mysql, magento

As the title stated, I'm looking to query all in-stock products by category ID in Magento 2. And if possible to get only the parent(config) IDs if simple has stock, not sure if I make sense?

```
SELECT p.entity_id as product_id, p.sku, c.is_in_stock 
FROM catalog_product_entity as p
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item as c 
ON p.entity_id = c.product_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all products that are in stock for a category id:

```
SELECT product.entity_id as product_id, product.sku, stock_item.is_in_stock FROM catalog_product_entity as product
    INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item as stock_item ON product.entity_id = stock_item.product_id
    INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as cat_prod on product.entity_id = cat_prod.product_id
    WHERE cat_prod.category_id=XXX and stock_item.is_in_stock=1;
```

If you only want the configurables, just add the condition like so: `and product.type_id='configurable'`

Comment: This is perfect! One tweak? https://i.ibb.co/PGrtNvt/help.png

Comment: What you want then is to get visible products. You can only do this for 1 store a time, because visibility is store scope specific. Add this: ```INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=product.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=0 AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4)```

Comment: Modified to INNER JOIN catalog_product_flat_5 as cat_index on cat_index.entity_id = cat_prod.product_id AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4)